# How to pass a name to a function like dplyr::distinct()

Tags: r

I have a list of five data frames full of user responses to a survey.

In each of these data frames, the second column is the user id number. Some of the users took the survey multiple times, and I am trying to weed out the duplicate responses and just keep the first record.

The naming conventions are fairly standard, so the column in the first data frame is called akin to *survey1_id* and the second is *survey2_id*, etc. with the exception being that the column in the third data frame is called *survey3a_id*.

So basically what I tried to do was this:

```
for (i in seq(1,5)) {
  newdata <- distinct(survey_list[[i]], grep(names("^survey.*_id$", survey_list[[i]]), value = TRUE))
}
```

But this doesn't work.
I originally thought it was just because the grep output had quotes around it, but I tried to strip them with `noquote()` and that didn't work. I then realized that `distinct()` doesn't actually evaluate the second argument, it just takes it literally, so I tried to force it to evaluate using `eval()`, but that didn't work. (Not sure I really expected it to.)

So now I'm kind of stuck. I don't know if the best solution is just to write five individual lines of code or, for a more generalizable solution, to sort and compare item-by-item in a loop? Was just hoping for a cleaner solution. I'm kind of new to this stuff.

Comment: most NSE dplyr functions have a `*_` alternative, so try `dplyr::distinct_`

Comment: Also look at `vignette("nse")` for more information about non-standard evaluation (NSE) when it comes to dplyr

Comment: `names` is in the wrong spot. Also, you could use a self-join to avoid SE, if you like: `survey_list[[i]] %>% select(matches("^survey.*_id$")) %>% distinct() %>% left_join(survey_list[[i]])`